# Flutter : How to use String outside async function?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

GetUserData() is getting a String and turning it into String encodedMap and returning it but i cant seem to get turn this String global with static, Can anyone help me Make encodedMap a not future string that i can use everywhere

```
Future getUserData() async {
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   
 String encodedMap = sharedPreferences.getString('TagMap') ?? '';
 return encodedMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that in this method since `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` returns a Future.

You have to `await` the call to `getUserData()`.

Comment: you can see my trick it's useful also you can do it as a services

Comment: Sure, but a couple of things to consider... 1) It is _not_ guaranteed that the cache held by SharedPreferences that you create when getting that instance is in sync with the values on the device. 2)  I'm not really fond of the global variable declaration, even if you'd do it as a service it is in essence the same thing in this case if you are just wrapping the sharedPreferences variable in another construct.

But I'll rephrase my answer sligthly to avoid misunderstandings :)

Comment: In order to use await i would have to be in async function, then it will still be stuck in async and cant be global. Can you explain a little bit more in detail cause i am a beginner when it comes to flutter.

Comment: You cannot make it "static global" in a good way because `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` returns a `Future` that you have to `await`. The reason for that is that it takes some time (usually just milliseconds) to read the preferences from disk. You can make a global service that fetch the latest preferences, but that will also be async, which is a GOOD thing. You don't want to lock your UI waiting for preferences to be fetched. Read more about async/await/Futures here: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Answer (score 0):

defined

```
late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

above of main function
then in main function do this

```
void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
sharedPreferences= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();;
runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

then when open app its be a global variable you can use it every where in app